# "Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance" but correct code?

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I am using Eloquent ORM with a many to many (n to n) relationship between users(players) and rooms(sessions), where users are attached to a room. They are able to play cards (scrum) in order to value an software issue through their card estimation.

When I load my view, which uses an optional {{id?}} parameter, it looks into my DB::Class and finds the room through the parameter.

The problem is, when I want to access the id attribute of my attached user to display the received information in my view. Although my debug shows, that I receive the correct data, I get the error mentioned above.

My View:
"cards.blade.php"

```
<h1 align="center"><u>Userid</u> {{$currentUser->id}}</h1>
<h1 align="center"><u>Username:</u> {{$currentUser->name}}</h1>
<h1 align="center"><u>Your estimation is:</u> {{$currentUser->userValue}}</h1>
<h1 align="center">Last updated: {{$currentRoom->updated_at->diffForHumans() ?? ''}}</h1>
<h1 align="center">@if ($currentUser->isAdmin === 0 || null )
    'You are sadly not an admin'
    @else 'You are an admin'
    @endif</h1>
<h1 align="center">Room Number: {{$currentRoom->id}}</h1>
```

"SessionController.php@getPlayerInfo"

```
  public function getPlayerInfo($id)

    {


        $currentRoom = Session::findOrFail($id);
        $currentUser = $currentRoom->users;

        $tmp = $currentUser->id;
        dd($currentUser);

        return view('sessions.cards')
            ->with('currentUser', $currentUser)
            ->with('currentRoom', $currentRoom);
    }
```

"web.php"

```
Route::get('play/{id?}', 'SessionController@getPlayerInfo')
    ->name('sessions.cards')
    ->middleware('auth');
```

> dd($currentUser) output:

```
Collection {#305 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => User {#302 ▼
      #fillable: array:3 [▶]
      #hidden: array:2 [▶]
      #casts: array:1 [▶]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "users"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:10 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "name" => "admin"
        "email" => "admin@email.com"
        "email_verified_at" => null
        "password" => "$2y$10$AhpAyD2NR2TW.kBYOMzTAe1kfRh73CtMhRxaGH0Bi2OrhPcSA65f."
        "userValue" => null
        "isAdmin" => null
        "remember_token" => null
        "created_at" => "2019-11-13 10:13:20"
        "updated_at" => "2019-11-13 10:13:20"
      ]
      #original: array:12 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:1 [▶]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #visible: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      #rememberTokenName: "remember_token"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the `dd` implies, your `$currentUser` contains a `collection`, so it's not a single record. You have to loop through its content to get a single user. Something like this:

```
@foreach ($currentUser as $user)
    {{ $user->id }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks! Solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

It's a collection.Use foreach like

```
@foreach($curretUser as $cuser)

<h1 align="center"><u>Userid</u> {{$cuser->id}}</h1>
<h1 align="center"><u>Username:</u> {{$cuser->name}}</h1>
<h1 align="center"><u>Your estimation is:</u> {{$cuser->userValue}}</h1>
<h1 align="center">Last updated: {{$currentRoom->updated_at->diffForHumans() ?? ''}}</h1>
<h1 align="center">@if ($cuser->isAdmin === 0 || null )
    'You are sadly not an admin'
    @else 'You are an admin'
    @endif</h1>
<h1 align="center">Room Number: {{$currentRoom->id}}</h1>
@endforeach
```